# Listview with popup on selection

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to make a listview in which the selected buttons produce a popup with different information depending on which list button was selected. Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: It's better to explain what you tried, and how it fails, but if you don't have anything yet, i'd suggest looking at RecycleView instead of ListView (that we are deprecating, in favor of RecycleView), it's easier, more flexible, and more performant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView has been deprecated since Kivy version 1.10.0. In the example below, we are using Recycleview.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty


class MessageBox(Popup):

    def popup_dismiss(self):
        self.dismiss()


class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior, RecycleBoxLayout):
    """ Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. """
    selected_value = StringProperty('')
    btn_info = ListProperty(['Button 0 Text', 'Button 1 Text', 'Button 2 Text'])


class SelectableButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):
    """ Add selection support to the Label """
    index = None

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        """ Catch and handle the view changes """
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableButton, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

    def on_press(self):
        self.parent.selected_value = 'Selected: {}'.format(self.parent.btn_info[int(self.id)])

    def on_release(self):
        MessageBox().open()


class RV(RecycleView):
    rv_layout = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': "Button " + str(x), 'id': str(x)} for x in range(3)]


class TestApp(App):
    title = "RecycleView Button Popup Demo"

    def build(self):
        return RV()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<MessageBox>:
    title: 'Popup Message Box'
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: app.root.rv_layout.selected_value
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            text: 'OK'
            on_press:
                root.dismiss()

<SelectableButton>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0.0, 0.9, 0.1, 0.3)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<RV>:
    rv_layout: layout
    viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        id: layout
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 0.1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: "vertical"
```

### Output

[image]